# "unqualified destination" error with git subtree push

Tags: git, heroku

I just created a new Heroku app and I don't manage to push the subtree folder `backend` of my repo (branch `staging`) to the newly created app `myapp-staging` (no branch yet).

Here is how I push the subtree:

```
git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix=backend staging`:master
```

An the related error:

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git'
```

I tried `git fetch heroku`. What does this "unqualified destination" mean? Shouldn't this command create the distant branch?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, got an idea thanks to http://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/

I tried:

```
git subtree split --prefix=bakcend -b test
git push heroku test:master
```

And it worked like a charm. May the problem would be with the creation of the branch using the subtree command...

Comment: Your solution works, but I am wondering why the first approach does not work. Because it is pointed as the right way of doing it in many places.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417845/pushing-a-large-github-repo-fails-with-unable-to-push-to-unqualified-destination), you can push to `refs/heads/master` to fix this problem, after which you can change back to `master`, although I'm still not entirely sure /why/ this works.

```
# run this once
git push origin master:refs/heads/master

# now you can use this forever
git push origin master
```